# Connections between Mersenne Primes and Codes

Tags: coding-theory, mersenne-numbers

I recently watched the video for the talk [The Biggest Known Prime Number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IWn5TA81MI) (slides located [here](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2018/05/mersennetalkCTNT.pdf)) by Keith Conrad, which is on Mersenne primes $M_n = 2^n-1$.
It is well-known that such numbers can be prime only if $n$ is prime, but that this condition is not sufficient for primality of $M_n$.
The smallest counterexample is $M_{11} = 2^{11} -1 = 23\cdot 87$.
Conrad's talk includes the remark:

> That $2^{11}−1$ has factor 23 is related to an important construction in coding theory called the perfect binary Golay code(a special subset of 23-dimensional space over integers mod 2)

My questions are:

1. What is the relation precisely?
2. Are there further relations between divisors of "Mersenne composites" and coding-theoretic constructions?

Comment: This is a potentially interesting question, but my educated guess for an answer to part 2 is "No". The existence of the binary Golay code relies on several miracles in addition to $M_{11}$ being reducible. You may want to look up *Leech Lattice* to get started on *all* the miracles :-)

Comment: bitxoring with them flips all bits ... bitanding with then is pointless .

Answer (score 2):

The connection is much simpler than I was imagining. It is well-known that the binary Golay code is *perfect*.
A code $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^n$ is called *perfect* if Hamming balls of radius $(d-1)/2$ centered at each codeword $c\in\mathcal{C}$ partition $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Note that the size of a Hamming ball of radius $r$ within $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is $1 + \binom{n}{1}+\dots+\binom{n}{r}$.
For this to partition the whole space, this quantity must be equal to *exactly* $|\mathbb{F}_2^n|/|\mathcal{C}| = 2^{n-k}$, where $k$ is the rank of the code.
So we get the condition:

$$1 + \binom{n}{1}+\dots + \binom{n}{r} = 2^{n-k}\iff \binom{n}{1}+\dots + \binom{n}{r} = 2^{n-k}-1$$

As $n$ obviously divides $\sum_{i = 1}^r\binom{n}{i}$, a necessary condition for this equality (and therefore for $\mathcal{C}$ to be perfect) is for $n$ to divide $2^{n-k}-1$, hence $2^{11}-1$ being composite (and in particular being divisible by 23) is necessary for there to exist a rank 12 perfect code within $\mathbb{F}_2^{23}$.

There may be a deeper connection still, as perfect codes are much rarer than the above condition might imply. I'll probably leave this question open a few more days in case someone knows a deeper connection.

Comment: This much is well known. A relatively deep result (due to Tietäväinen and van Lint) says that a perfect binary code is either the Golay code of length 23 or it has minimum distance three (when several lengths are possible). I refrained from answering because A) while divisibility by $23$ is necessary for this construction, as an explanation this is IMO a bit too tenous for other reducible Mersenne primes do not lead to similar constructions, B) Keith Conrad regularly visits this site and may want to clarify himself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree that in light of the above the answer to 2 is likely "no", as the condition above boils down to the condition $\exists k : n\mid 2^{n-k}-1$ being necessary for a rank $k$ dimension $n$ perfect binary code to exist. But, as you say, there are very few perfect codes, so this condition is likely "too weak" to really be interesting by itself (for example, we could run this same argument for $n = 87$, the other factor of $2^{11}-1$, and get potential parameters, to get $(n, k) = (87, 76)$, but its not clear that this dimension/rank is interesting in coding theory at all).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a direct connection between composite $M_n$'s and coding theory.
Such a composite Mersenne number exists iff there is a (non-degenerate) binary irreducible cyclic code of dimension n and length a non-trivial divisor of $M_n.$ Of course, not all irreducible cyclic codes are as exciting as the $[23,11],$ the dual of the perfect binary Golay!

Comment: Do you have pointers for this? Or does it hold because any cyclic code corresponds to an ideal in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/ (x^n -1)$, and $2^n-1$ factoring somehow corresponds with $x^n-1$ factoring?

Comment: An irreducible cyclic code is a cyclic code such that its check poly  $h$  is irreducible . Let $k$ be its degree. Then $h$ generates the field $GF(2^k).$ A root of order the length $n$ of the code must live in that field and therefore $ n| 2^k-1.$